# Get the value from ListBox C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, listbox

I have the one Dictionary variable and Listbox.

Dictionary variable have the following values,

```
first
Second
```

ListBox can have

```
first
Second
Third
```

Expected Output is : Third

Now I need the get the value from Listbox which is not available in the Dictionary?How to Compare the Listbox with Dictionary Value?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some code sample around how you are using your dictionary and listbox in code.  Also check out except that will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("First");
            list.Add("second");
            list.Add("third");

            Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            dictionary.Add( 1,"First");
            dictionary.Add(2,"second");

            foreach (var li in list)
            {

                if (!dictionary.ContainsValue(li))
                {                  
                    Console.WriteLine(li);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```